# Injecting routing using symfony2 extension class / semantic configuration

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

How come there isn't (or if there is please point me to it) a repeatable pattern for consistently and safely enabling injection of a third party bundle's routing resource (`/Resources/config/routing.yml`) that happens "magically," similarly to the way to `services.yml` file is loaded in the `FooBundle/DependencyInjection/AcmeFooExtension` class's load method?

I understand that the "normal" practice is to just reference the bundle's routing resource in the application's routing.yml file ... but why can't it happen automagically?

I thought the reason might be that there could be route naming conflicts between multiple autoloaded bundles' routing files - but that could easily be resolved by some configuration parameters that would effectively insulate the different bundles' routes.

Appreciate the information.

Comment: I guess it's a better practice to *say* which routes are going to be exposed. If you don't want to type all the routes, I advise you to switch to [annotations](http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony-devs/s-J_Ceidj9A

Comment: @WouterJ thanks for the link. Glad I'm not the only one who was curious about this topic.